# How to change this json like string to json with python

Tags: python, json

// [ { "id": "304466804484872" ,"t" : "GOOG" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "720.01" ,"l_fix" : "720.01" ,"l_cur" : "720.01" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"10:23AM EST" ,"lt" : "Nov 10, 10:23AM EST" ,"lt_dts" : "2015-11-10T10:23:21Z" ,"c" : "-4.88" ,"c_fix" : "-4.88" ,"cp" : "-0.67" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.67" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "724.89" } ]

I tried with

> u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>
> content = u.read()
> obj = json.loads(content[3:])

but return all element with u'
then i do

> map(lambda x:x.encode(acsii), obj)

but get only keys
how to get values as well?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I tried json.load but seems cannot work.

Comment: Makes sense, because `json.load` takes a file object and not a string.

Comment: Hint: there's another function in the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module that works on strings instead of file objects...

Comment: works with obj = json.loads(content[3:]) but have u'string' infront of every string

Comment: the u just means its using unicode - no big deal if you print the items they will be basic strings (or you use them that way) unless its an actual unicode character string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after converting:

```
for k, v in obj[0].items():
    print k, j
```

this will print:

```
c -4.88
ccol chr
e NASDAQ
ltt 10:23AM EST
cp_fix -0.67
c_fix -4.88
l 720.01
s 0
lt Nov 10, 10:23AM EST
pcls_fix 724.89
t GOOG
lt_dts 2015-11-10T10:23:21Z
l_fix 720.01
cp -0.67
id 304466804484872
l_cur 720.01
```

see no 'u' there